# How to configure Pymur?

Tags: python, terminal, configure

I have been trying to build and install [pymur](https://github.com/bmuller/pymur) by following the steps [here](http://findingscience.com/pymur/index.html) . When I reach the ./configure step I get a "No such file or directory". Out of desperation I tried running configure.ac file however I get this error:

```
   File "./configure.ac", line 1
     AC_INIT([pymur], [0.0], [mullerb@musc.edu])
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mullerb@musc.edu` is supposed to be a string type value, which means it needs to be wrapped in quotes -> `"mullerb@musc.edu"`

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I tried that but I kept getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following:

```
 brew install autoconf automake libtool
 brew install boost double-conversion gflags glog libevent
```

Comment: Congrats for solving it. Dont forget to mark the answer as a solution ;)